# could not interpret id generator strategy : x.y.z.CustomIDGenerator

Tags: java, hibernate, id-generation

i've facing Hibernate mapping issue : could not interpret ID generator Strategy :  
Stack Trace :

```
Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-14" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryMTS' defined in OSGi resource[classpath:spring-beans.xml|bnd.id=288|bnd.sym=persistence]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.db.model.UserProfiles]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)
        at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.db.model.UserProfiles]
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorFactory.create(IdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createIdentifierGenerator(SimpleValue.java:175)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:230)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1341)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: could not interpret id generator strategy: com.db.custom.id.generator.UserProfileCustomIDGenerator
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorFactory.getIdentifierGeneratorClass(IdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:151)
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGeneratorFactory.create(IdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:124)
        ... 23 more
```

My Custome ID generator class looks like :

```
public class UserProfileCustomIDGenerator extends IdentityGenerator{

@Override
public Serializable generate(SessionImplementor session, Object object)
        throws HibernateException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        UserProfiles userProfile = (UserProfiles)object;
        if(userProfile.getId() != 0){
            return userProfile.getId();
        }else{
            Serializable id = super.generate(session, object);
            return id;
        }

}

}
```

I've googling but can't get solution.
Please let me know if any mistake i have done or solution is there.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `IdentifierGenerator` instead of `IdentityGenerator`.

Comment: If we implement IdentifierGenerator then we can't call super.generate method when UserProfile Id is not set.
IF we want to use default strategy when userProfileId is not set explicitly then we have to extends <StrategyGenerator> class.